# Simple function request (altering `max` function)

Tags: macros

Currently, using `\max{1,2}` will print:

`max 1,2`.

How do I alter it such that it prints:

`max{1,2}`,

without having to use `\max{\{1,2\}}` in text?

Note: I'm fine with making a new function called `\max2` that achieves this (if overwriting the original function is a problem for some reason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\max` does not take an argument so you don't need `\max{\{1,2\}}` just `\max\{1,2\}` . However if you want to save yourself those two backslashes

```
\let\oldmax\max
\def\max#1{\oldmax\{#1\}}
```

Comment: In LaTeX, `\max` is defined as a `mathop` item that can take subscript limits, viz., `\def\max{\mathop{\operator@font max}}`. With your setup, the command `$\max_z{a,b}$` is legal but results in something rather awful-looking. It may be wise to leave `\max` alone and provide an entirely new command, e.g., `\def\maxi#1{\textrm{max}\{#1\}}`.